# Who can help me decrypt

Tags: encryption

There is a string:

`51141010379856000173550010000111151512908026` which after encryption becomes:

`l4yAOVWeHlk4tnNu3HlJnxMUppeOWCpIqmRKkUPQHlgNawdYMDK2mnieDazPkJuI`

`51141010379856000173550010000111261161046942` which after encryption becomes

`l4yAOVWeHlk4tnNu3HlJnxMUppeOWCpIqmRKkUPQHligG0uPAROGtDzaPrLoYldL`

Another 2 examples:

`51141003237583000914550010002095541000085781`  becomes

`73L0zaw06WGCxKQIKkiQnlvav8XyVUyePmYyF+PcWhWO2dCVrIOVxV5tj8EX6e40`

`51141003237583000914550010002097571001239076` becomes

`73L0zaw06WGCxKQIKkiQnlvav8XyVUyeVT3qU6uWLXXbpG71J5Q8TzArk/DBR+Vw`

Who can help me to discover how the second string is calculated?

All first strings are 44 characters long; the second string is 64 bits long

Comment: It's obvious that this is a 64-bit block cipher used in ECB mode with the output encoded in Base64.  If you want more information than that, you'll need to provide far more detail.

Comment: Take a look at the outputs. Do you see how the similar strings result in similar output? This is not encryption, or even a hash - this is encoding.

Comment: @schroeder, similar strings produce similar output, but if you break the input and output into blocks, similar input produces wildly different output.

Comment: @Mark Agreed. I'm not sure how that applies here, though.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the number was converted into hexadecimal, and then put through base64. This is only coding, no key was used, it is not encryption.

To reverse it, you can do

`echo "73L0zaw06WGCxKQIKkiQnlvav8XyVUyeVT3qU6uWLXXbpG71J5Q8TzArk/DBR+Vw" | base64 -d | xxd` to see the value in hexadecimal. Then use Python for instance to convert the hex number found into a decimal number.

EDIT : It seems I did not test my answer, and my intuition by seeing the results was wrong. It has been encrypted. Thanks Mark to testing it for me, and sorry for answering too quickly.

Comment: I tried decoding using your method, and got "36854581520381076119699552340460026418036238082260239918970332266018514687795934443533859662849399011636086422627696".  Sure, the last digit is correct, but the rest of it is wrong.